# Critique my web page's color and typography

Tags: typography, interface-design, critique

This is a task management web app. I'm looking for design critiques and feedback in terms of typography, colors, and UX.

You can [see the site working here](http://invis.io/78QOCF9W) with comments to specific areas where I'm looking feedback on.

[image]

Comment: If feedback is only visible on the invis.io site, and there's no screenshot here, then this question provides no value at all for future visitors. If you include a screenshot in the question, and we get answers here, I'll keep the question. Otherwise I'll have to close it as being of no value.

Comment: Only comment I'll offer in it's current question state (see Alan's comment, it's very valid).... it's too wide. In my opinion, there's **never** a reason for a minimum width of more than 1400 pixels... ever. If you can't do it in 1000px, then you need to rethink.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too wide, however I want to give you some feedback about color coding.

The main color coding I see in your screenshot is red and green.

You should know that about 8% of men in some  europenian countries are color blind in terms of red - green differentiation,  plus IMHO most of the users of your app will be men (women too, but I believe less than men), thus your color coding  cannot be differentiated by at least some of the users.

In such a case I would think about iconing instead of color-only based coding.

Look here for some useful information -http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloradd

Comment: Good point. I generally use [this tool](http://colororacle.cartography.ch/) to check for color-blindness.